# RNFB_ANDROID_PERMISSIONS=true command showing error on windows

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

installing react-native-fetch-blob was successful and linking it is also done. But when i run 'RNFB_ANDROID_PERMISSIONS=true' command it show command not found. how can i fix it

Answer (score 1):

Please try following solution, might be work for you.

['RNFB_ANDROID_PERMISSIONS' is not recognized](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/issues/519#issuecomment-329440324)

Comment: I tried adding RNFB_ANDROID_PERMISSIONS with value true inside user variables on windows 10 but I am still getting permission denied error why so ? see screenshot:  https://imgur.com/a/fPUgBPS and https://imgur.com/a/PJy9MQ5